# Why are there more then 2 axis possible in MDX and where can I use it?

Tags: mdx, olap

I've been googling around to get this question answered. There is a max of 128 Axis you can use in MDX language, but I cannot find a single application that uses it nor a purpose of doing it.

There is this ADOMD.Net component i could use to write my own application that can work with it, but there is no single example i can find of why i should do it, and also no example of what people do with it in their applications.

Can someone please explain this to me ?

Comment: "Why are there more than 2 axis possible" - Because a cube can have more than two dimension. I guess not much work was done on this because it really is not needed. Using cross join you can get data from multiple dimensions very easily. Maybe MS realized that it's not worth investing their time.

Comment: It is an assumption that might be or might not be true, there must have been a reason why this is developed.

Comment: not required. There are lots of keywords in SQL Server too which are reserved for future use. Similarly the developers of MDX could have prudently kept this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use as many axes as you like in a sub-select - it is very useful there for doing filtering.

An example:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].MEMBERS ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[1]
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[8]
    } ON 0
   ,[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Country].[Canada] ON 1
   ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[1] ON 2
  FROM [Adventure Works]
)
WHERE [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```

This returns the following:

[image]

---

Edit

I suspect that the ability to use more than 2 axes had an element of future-proofing the language at the time it was created. So the authors were unsure how it would be used and thus built in this functionality.

Comment: Great example, didn't know I could use that. Do you  have also a different application besides a filter and a 3-axis graph ?

Comment: This can be also achieved using a cross join.

Comment: @SouravA this is an example of using more than two axes: it isn't supposed to do anything meaningful - simply illustrate the use of more than two axes.

Comment: Can I assume that, the more axis I use, the multidimentionally granular the tuples are that I get ? Like a group by that contains multiple columns in regular SQL ?

Comment: I understand that whytheq. Simply driving the point that this is *just another way*, not the only way(to the OP). Again backs my guess why there aren't many softwares/application which work with multiple axes.

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko - every tuple you use has _every_ dimension inside it: if you do not explicitly add a specific member to a tuple then the dimension's `[All]` member is still within that tuple.

Comment: @whytheq, well described, it was what I mean only could not descibe it as well as you ;) I assume the answer as yes

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you'd like to display your results using a 3D chart, I guess using 3 axes is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Ok, that i still can imagine. 1 option to use 4 or 5 axis is to filter, like in the previous answer of whyteq, but is there a usage example for 3 + then besides filtering?